# ag: silver searcher: ignore multiple formats

Tags: regex, bash, grep, ag

with the silver searcher, how can i ignore any files with multiple specific extensions? for example, i've tried:

```
$ ag --ignore '*.js|*.txt' 'foobar'
```

this doesn't work. i don't want a `.agignore' file.

Comment: not really a programming Q, but how about multiple `--ignore '*.js' --ignore '*.txt'` ? Good luck.

Answer (score 4):

Multiple `--ignore` options works as `shellter` suggests in his comment on the question:

```
ag --ignore '*.js' --ignore '*.txt' foobar
```

If you want to get fancy, use a process substitution as your temporary .agignore file:

```
ag -p <(printf "*.%s\n" js txt) foobar
```

Comment: Plus one for the dynamic generation of .agignore file.

Answer (score 0):

This

```
'*.js|*.txt' 'foobar'
```

can be combined into one pattern:

```
(\.(js|txt)$)|^foobar$
```

A shell pattern might need some of those characters escaped.

[PCRE demo](https://regex101.com/r/TLZ2Xg/1)